# Displaying the 64 hexagrams of the Yi Jing (using Unicode range 4DC0 up 4DFF)

Tags: xetex, unicode, cjk

I'm writing a book and I need to include the range of Unicode characters **4DC0** - **4DFF** up to display the hexagrams of the Chinese book Yi Jing  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching

I've used the various packages and I've also read all the questions about how to use Unicode here in the Community. I am a *beginner* in LaTeX.

My environment: MikTeX with TeXnicCenter with option XeLaTeX, Windows 8.
I saved my document in UTF-8.

Just a comment (*it is solved*): I can display all Chinese characters using the CJK package?

Here we have an example. But how to display each hexagram in LaTeX?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Ching_hexagram_01

Please, I ask for a complete example that works for my environment described. Do not write things like *"do this"* or *"use it."*

I hope understanding and help.

Below is an example of the packages that I am using

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[brazil,portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % Type1-font for non-english texts and characters
\usepackage{graphicx}   % For loading graphic files
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, pxfonts}  % permite simbolos matemáticos
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{aecompl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%----------------------------------------------
% Unicode environment
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{autofe}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{unicode=true}
\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{CJKutf8}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{4DC0}{\hex1}
\newunicodechar{4DC2}{\hex2}
\catcode"4DC0=\qian
%----------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

$hex1$    $hex2$
\qian
\unichar{4DC0}
\char"4DC0
Hexagram \hex1

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `ucs` and `inputenc` packages must not be used with XeLaTeX (and also `ae` and `aecompl`, which should *never* be used). I'm very dubious also towards `CJKutf8`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ucs` and `inputenc` package must not be used with XeLaTeX as well as `fontenc`, in general, but the last one may have its uses; never load `ae` and `aecompl`: they are obsolete.

`CJKutf8` package is a mixture of `CJK` package and `inputenc` package with `utf8` option. it is also not used in XeLaTeX.

You don't need any CJK package in order to print some glyphs: just find a font that has them. On my system, I found DejaVu Sans. So I defined a macro that takes as argument the glyph's number (from 0 to 63, it would be easy to start at 1, if you so desire).

For some reason, apparently due to how `xeCJK` decides what's Chinese and what's not, one has to declare the font twice: for hexagrams it has to be declared with `\newCJKfontfamily` and for trigrams with `\newfontfamily` (or `\newfontface` that's more efficient for a font that's not required to change shape according to the context).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xeCJK}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont{LiSong Pro} % or another font supporting Chinese

\newCJKfontfamily{\dejavusanszh}{DejaVu Sans} % this font has the required glyphs
\newfontface{\dejavusans}{DejaVu Sans} % this font has the required glyphs

\newcommand{\iching}[1]{{\dejavusanszh\char\numexpr"4DC0+#1}}
\newcommand{\trigram}[1]{{\dejavusans\char\numexpr"2630+#1}}

\begin{document}

Yì Jīng 易經 - Hex: \iching{8} \trigram{7}

\trigram{0} \trigram{1} \trigram{2} \trigram{3}
\trigram{4} \trigram{5} \trigram{6} \trigram{7}


\iching{0}
\iching{1}
\iching{2}
\iching{3}
\iching{4}
\iching{5}
\iching{6}
\iching{7}

\iching{8}
\iching{9}
\iching{10}
\iching{11}
\iching{12}
\iching{13}
\iching{14}
\iching{15}

\iching{16}
\iching{17}
\iching{18}
\iching{19}
\iching{20}
\iching{21}
\iching{22}
\iching{23}

\iching{24}
\iching{25}
\iching{26}
\iching{27}
\iching{28}
\iching{29}
\iching{20}
\iching{31}

\iching{32}
\iching{33}
\iching{34}
\iching{35}
\iching{36}
\iching{37}
\iching{38}
\iching{39}

\iching{40}
\iching{41}
\iching{42}
\iching{43}
\iching{44}
\iching{45}
\iching{46}
\iching{47}

\iching{48}
\iching{49}
\iching{50}
\iching{51}
\iching{52}
\iching{53}
\iching{54}
\iching{55}

\iching{56}
\iching{57}
\iching{58}
\iching{59}
\iching{60}
\iching{61}
\iching{62}
\iching{63}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An alternative method is to declare Yijing Hexagrams Symbols as non-CJK characters in `xeCJK`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\xeCJKsetcharclass{"4DC0}{"4DFF}{0} % set Yijing Hexagrams Symbols as non-CJK characters

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setCJKmainfont{LiSong Pro} % or another font supporting Chinese

\newfontface{\dejavusans}{DejaVu Sans} % this font has the required glyphs

\newcommand{\iching}[1]{{\dejavusans\char\numexpr"4DC0+#1}}
\newcommand{\trigram}[1]{{\dejavusans\char\numexpr"2630+#1}}

\begin{document}

Yì Jīng 易經 - Hex: \iching{8} \trigram{7}
......

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works. But Chinese characters do not appear (and have always worked). 

If I put as "comments" lines: 
\setCJKmainfont{DFKai-SB}
\ setCJKmonofont MingLiU {} 

The opposite occurs: the Hexagram and do not appear to be returning Chinese characteres exbidos normally. That is, one or the other (or hexagrams Chinese characters).

I made several attempts at combinations. And I found that conflict happens past 2 lines above.

I try to put the code but the maximum size is exceeded
 
\begin{document}

Yì Jīng 易經 - Hexagrams: \iching{8} and \iching{60}

\end{document}

Comment: @JWainer HTML doesn't work in comments. You asked about those glyphs. Please, explain better in your question what are hexagrams.

Comment: \documentclass{book}
% Unicode
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface{\dejavusans}{DejaVu Sans} % this font has the required glyphs
\newcommand{\iching}[1]{{\dejavusans\char\numexpr"4DC0+#1}}
% CJK
\usepackage{xeCJK} 
\usepackage{CJK} 
\usepackage{pinyin}
\XeTeXlinebreaklocale "zh" 
\XeTeXlinebreakskip = 0pt plus 1pt 
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman} % rm
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Arial}           % sf
\setmonofont{Courier New}                       % tt
\setCJKmainfont{DFKai-SB}
\setCJKmonofont{MingLiU}
\begin{document}
Yì Jīng 易經 - Hex: \iching{8}
\end{document}

Comment: @JWainer Use `\newCJKfontfamily` instead of `\newfontface` (move the line after `\usepackage{xeCJK}`. I don't think you should load `CJK` and `pinyin` that aren't thought for XeLaTeX.

Comment: Your solution worked perfectly for any hexagram.  

Only a new application, complementary. I want to also use trigrams.  

I duplicated their initial line. And I put the name "\trigram".  

\newcommand{\iching}[1]{{\dejavusans\char\numexpr"4DC0+#1}}  
\newcommand{\trigram}[1]{{\dejavusans\char\numexpr"2630+#1}}   
 
But the trigrams do not work. I am beginner. I do not know what I should change the 2nd line to also display trigrams?

Comment: @JWainer I added the requested trigrams; it's difficult to understand why we need two different names pointing to the same font, but the documentation of `xeCJK` is only in Chinese. I guess it has to do with how the package decides something is CJK or not.

Comment: `xeCJK` now treats the “Yijing Hexagrams Symbols” as CJK characters. I don't know whether it is a good choice. `\xeCJKsetcharclass{"4DC0}{"4DFF}{0}` would also solve the problem.

Comment: @LeoLiu I believe there is *no* good choice for every case, as each character can belong to only one class at a given time. Maybe there can be an option for switching classes.

Answer (score 3):

You are loading a lot of package which either don't work or will clash with xelatex. To get the glyphs you can use a code like this, but you will have to find a suitable font first.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
{\fontspec{UnicodeBMPFallback.ttf} % replace by a real font with the glyphs
 ^^^^4dc0
 \char"4DC0}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As another solution, its works. But Chinese characters do not appear (and have always worked).  

If I put as "comments" lines:  
\ setCJKmainfont-SB} {DFKai  
\ setCJKmonofont MingLiU {}  

The opposite occurs: the Hexagram and do not appear to be returning Chinese characteres exbidos normally. That is, one or the other (or hexagrams Chinese characters).    

Please, how can I do also appear ideograms and hexagrams?  

\begin{document}  
Yì Jīng 易經  

{\fontspec{DejaVu Sans} 
 ^^^^4dc0  
 \char"4DC0}  

\end{document}

Comment: @JWainer: No the font I used is a fall back font for unicode. It doesn't contain the actual glyphs but shows only the numbers. I don't know which fonts have the glyphs you are looking for.