# How do I display trigrams from the Unicode miscellaneous symbols block?

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode, input-encodings

How to encode special unicode symbols as in [here](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%98%93%E7%B6%93%E5%85%AD%E5%8D%81%E5%9B%9B%E5%8D%A6%E7%AC%A6%E8%99%9F_(Unicode%E5%8D%80%E6%AE%B5)) in latex?

[image]

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132437/4427

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My apologies for misunderstanding your question the first time.  Here is a template that reproduces the example you gave in XeLaTeX.  (Okay, I replaced the tildes with en dashes.)

```
\documentclass[varwidth = 10cm, preview]{standalone}
% This document class is appropriate for a TeX.SX MWE.  In a real document,
% you will want to change it.
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

% Workaround for a bug in Babel 3.22:
\babelprovide[script = CJK, language = {Chinese Simplified}]{chinese-simplified}

% This example uses the Noto font family.  Any OpenType font should work.
\babelfont{rm}[Scale = 1.0, Ligatures = TeX ]{Noto Serif}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase, Ligatures = TeX }
\babelfont{sf}{Noto Sans}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{rm}[Ligatures = Common]{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\babelfont[chinese-simplified]{sf}[Ligatures = Common]{Noto Sans CJK SC}

\newfontfamily\miscsymfont{DejaVu Sans}

\newunicodechar{：}{\foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{：}}
\newunicodechar{⚊}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"268A}}}
\newunicodechar{⚋}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"268B}}}
\newunicodechar{⚌}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"268C}}}
\newunicodechar{⚍}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"268D}}}
\newunicodechar{⚎}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"268E}}}
\newunicodechar{⚏}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"268F}}}
\newunicodechar{☰}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2630}}}
\newunicodechar{☱}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2631}}}
\newunicodechar{☲}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2632}}}
\newunicodechar{☳}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2633}}}
\newunicodechar{☴}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2634}}}
\newunicodechar{☵}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2635}}}
\newunicodechar{☶}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2636}}}
\newunicodechar{☷}{{\miscsymfont\symbol{"2637}}}
% Also define U+4DC0-U+4DFF.

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Miscellaneous Symbols (U+2600--U+26FF)：
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{兩儀：}U+268A--U+268B (⚊ ⚋)
        \item \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{四象：}U+268C--U+268F (⚌ ⚍ ⚎ ⚏)
        \item \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{八卦：}U+2630--U+2637 (☰ ☱ ☲ ☳ ☴ ☵ ☶ ☷)
      \end{itemize}
    \item \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{六爻符號：}
      \begin{itemize}
        \item \foreignlanguage{chinese-simplified}{六十四卦、易經：}U+4DC0--U+4DFF
      \end{itemize}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: Font sample of Chinese with Trigrams]

You need to load the trigram symbols from a font that contains them.  Another option would be to use `ucharclasses` with the character class `MiscellaneousSymbols`, although this does not play well with Babel.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  I do not have trouble in Chinese encoding and I am using ceCJK.  It is the special symbols I am having issue with.   I can input them ok (C-x 8 RET 2630), but it does not show in pdf output.

Comment: @TonyTan Sorry for misunderstanding. You mean the trigrams aren’t displaying? You’d want to make sure to load them from [a font that supports them](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2630/fontsupport.htm), for example DejaVu Sans. I’ll update my answer.

Comment: @TonyTan Thank you for the clarification. Is this new answer more what you were looking for?